# How to rewrite table using ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I'm trying to re-write table using javascript and ajax. Here request has been sent and response is arrived but innerHTML cannot re-write table content with response text.
Here is my code.

`<table>
    <tbody id='product1'>
       <tr>
          <td> Product Name:</td>
          <td>P1</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>`

Javascript

`function compareProd(prodID,tId){
        browse();
        var url = 'process.jsp';
        url += '?compareProd='+prodID;
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = changeProd(tId);
        xmlHttp.open('POST', url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function changeProd(tID) {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 'complete') {
            document.getElementById('product1').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }`

process.jsp
`<tr>
          <td> Product Name:</td>
          <td>P2</td>
       </tr>`

here response is arrived but cannot rewrite table.

Comment: your code is correct check product1 is unique on your page

Comment: Can you please put the entire table in a `div` and use the div's id in innerHTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it in single function and check like this, on assumption that you initialized `xmlHttp` request object.

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById('product1').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
};
```

Comment: xmlhttp.readyState is 0 what does it means?

it shows me response in console.

Comment: 0 mean request not initialized , check this out http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Comment: than what is the solution for this.?

Comment: try hitting the url which you are trying directly in browser address and see what you get

Comment: did you initilizae xmlHttp object like this xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: it shows me output what i want. and it also show me response in console.

Comment: yes i initialize in browse function.
 `function browse(){
   if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   if (xmlHttp == null) {
    alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
    return false;
   } 
  }`

Comment: @rajeshkakawat you should use `xmlHttp.readyState` and `xmlHttp.status` and not `xmlhttp.readyState` or `xmlhttp.status`. You can give any valid name but it has to be consistent like OP did.

Comment: i just simply call browse() function in changeProd(tID) and it works. thanks